# Initilize Spring application with start.spring.io

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to know which dependencies I need to select inside this [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) to start an Restful API Spring Application that use Hibernate with MySQL database.

I have make some tries but unable to figure it out.

Comment: Spring web + Spring Data Jpa +MySQL Driver , you can use also "Spring Boot DevTools " to avoid restarting server  manually after code changes,  you need to configure Hibernate and connexion with DB in the application.properties files . this answer my help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930191/connect-mysql-to-spring-application

Answer (score 0):

You will need Spring Web WEB and Spring Data JPA, and some Database Driver.

The .pom will look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven Project then add these dependencies in pom.xml,

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
          <groupId>mysql</groupId>
          <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

If you are using Gradle Project then add these dependencies in build.gradle,

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```